# I am getting this error while starting eclipse .I have reinstalled it many times,still getting this error .?

Tags: java, linux, eclipse

```
!SESSION Wed Mar 28 19:04:50 IST 2018 ------------------------------------------
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.launcher 4 0 2018-03-28 19:04:50.629
!MESSAGE Exception launching the Eclipse Platform:
!STACK
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:626)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:584)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1438)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1414)
```

I am getting this error while starting eclipse .I have reinstalled it many times,still getting this error . ?

Answer (score 0):

First create a folder under `C drive` like `C:\Aaps`. Now Download the eclipse binary again from http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/eclipse-packages/. Now while installing the eclipse select/choose `C:\Aaps` as the installation directory (instead of `C:\Program Files (x86)`) and run the eclipse.exe from `C:\Aaps\Eclipse_xxx\` folder only.